# GUI toolkit with CSS support

Tags: css, user-interface, sdk, cross-platform

Are there any GUI toolkits for standalone desktop applications (the best case when it is cross-platform) which supports CSS component styling?

I know Adobe Flex but this is the worst case as it is not so good for standalone desktop applications.

Comment: I don't have a specific example, but it's very possible to embed a web-browser in a GUI, on any platform.  Then you get the permissions of a desktop app, with the simplicity of HTML/CSS.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand thanks! Yeah, last few days i recalled Flex and thought it may be used fo desktop applications...

Comment: Isn't it the purpose of XUL, Mozilla's toolkit ? Or I have missed something...

Answer (score 1):

There is JavaFX 2. It supports css use and fxml files! It's quite very good! I use it!

Answer (score 0):

What about https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL ?